# How do I select a parent element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, parent

I have a menu in which I'd like to set both the list item and link to the "active" class I've set up when on the active url.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="featured-projects">
     <li><a href="featured-project.php?id=1" title="Click to view 138 50th Street">138 50TH STREET</a></li>
     <li><a href="featured-project.php?id=2" title="Click to view 147 East 86th Street">147 EAST 86TH STREET</a></li>
     <li><a href="featured-project.php?id=3" title="Click to view 520 Fifth Avenue">520 FIFTH AVENUE</a></li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery:

```
$("#featured-projects li a").each(function() {   
    if(this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("li").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

How would I set the list item to active as well without setting *every* list item to active?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `parent()`. Well named as it is, it always selects the parent node(s) of the matched element(s). Full description here: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$("#featured-projects li a").each(function() {   
    if(this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active"); //Select the parent element of the link in question and add the class
    }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer satisfies you, it would be good karma (or whatever) to mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: can you edit this and explain why?...more karma coming to you

Comment: Yup. Explanation added. Although it is difficult to say much about what 'parent()' does, that it's name does not say already.